# Function of Tick or Ticker

Tags: html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

What is the use of tick function in easeljs. When to use it? What exactly does it do to a  stage? What is the exact format? I see different ways in which it has been called in different tutorials.

What is difference between tick and ticker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tick function on the Stage (and other display objects) advances all the child animations. Things like MovieClip and Sprite have frame-based animation, which are advanced the the next frame whenever they are ticked. You can turn off `updateOnTick` on the stage to prevent this.

The Ticker is a utility class that manages an actual heartbeat. It is a totally optional utility, but it creates an interval (using timeouts or requestAnimationFrame), and then dispatches events at a ~constant rate (the rate will be dependant on the performance on the device).

You can set the stage as a listener to the Ticker (instead of a custom handler function), and it will automatically call `update()` (and hence `tick()`) on the stage. This is the easiest usage. You can also manually call `stage.update()` in your own function to tick and redraw the stage. Note that using the stage as a listener guarantees that the stage will constantly update - so if you want to control it, then listen to the Ticker yourself, and manually call `stage.update()`.